# Missing MFC42D.dll in c++ project

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an old project that has been written for managing IP cameras. It was written in an old version of Visual Studio. When I load it to compile again and upgrade it in VS 2012. There is: **missing MFC42D.dll error** How can i fix it?
The error is:

> The program can't start because MFC42D.dll miising from your computer .Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

Comment: Your application is looking for the debug version of MFC42.DLL. That binary ships with Visual Studio 6. To get it, you need to install Visual Studio 6. Your other options are: Compile a release configuration and install the redistributable package for MFC v4.2, or move to a more recent implementation of MFC.

Comment: $llnspectable how can i move to more recent MFC ??

Comment: Recompile your program or the specific code parts and libraries with a newer VS Version.

Comment: *.D.DLL(s) are in this case debug dlls.  There is no licence to distribute these from MS and they are not included in the redistribution packages from MS.  You need to build a release version and/or change your project settings.

Comment: yeah! with release it works thank u dude.